# Leaving US with Ukrainian non-biometrical passport, spending long layover in EU outside the airport?

Tags: visas, eu

My friend is Ukrainian. She is going to the US from Ukraine soon, and on the way back she has a 9-hour layover in Paris CDG.

Her US visa is in a non-biometrical passport, which doesn’t allow to enter EU without a visa. But she also has a biometrical one, which allows her to travel to EU (in Ukraine people can have up to 2 passports for travelling abroad).

How can she exit the airport during layover to take a walk in the city?

UPD: the question is more about the usage of passports, not the timing. Will she be able to use the biometrical one to leave the airport, if the boarding pass will be for the non-biometrical one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I have two passports/nationalities. How do I use them when I travel?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52100/i-have-two-passports-nationalities-how-do-i-use-them-when-i-travel)

Comment: Which airport, and where does she want to go in Paris? It’s roughly 30 minutes from CDG to the Gare du Nord https://parisbytrain.com/charles-de-gaulle-airport-cdg-to-paris-by-train/ Allowing for Immigration on arrival, travel to/from the city, and Security prior to departure, her 9 hours could be closer to 3 or 4.

Comment: Anna, if you want to edit your question, please sign in to the same account you used to ask the question. Edits by people with the same username are not guarantied to be by the same person and are seen as suspect.

Comment: Anna, you can [merge](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) your two accounts ([this one](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/78678/anna) and [this one](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/78684/anna-kurylo)).

Comment: @Traveller Sure, which is plenty of time to see a little of Paris and much nicer than sitting in the airport.

Comment: @David Richerby Totally agree - I guess I’m just a cautious traveller :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

She can use her biometric passport to enter the Schengen area without a visa.  There's nothing requiring her to use the same passport in France that she used in the US.

If anyone asks why she's doing it, she can explain why she used the non-biometric passport for the US visa application, and that she's using the biometric passport to enter France because of the visa exemption.

> Will she be able to use the biometrical one to leave the airport, if the boarding pass will be for the non-biometrical one?

Yes.  The boarding pass is not irrevocably linked to a particular passport.  The immigration officers are unlikely to care much about her boarding pass when she leaves the airport, and when she returns she will just need to show that she has a boarding pass, that she is the person named on it, and that she hasn't overstayed in the Schengen area.  If they notice that the passport with the Schengen entry stamp isn't he one that she used to check in for her flight, she can show the other passport too and explain why she's using them both, as noted above.